# How to design the given format Qt 5 ui form designer

Tags: forms, qt, user-interface, qt5

I want to make a Dialog Box which looks something like this:

[image]

However I am unable to give the proper combination of spacers to attain this.

Giving the left horizontal spacer makes the image also shift to right which I do not want. And If I somehow shift the image to top left, then the button layout gets more to the right than the middle. How can this be done?

**Edit**: Adding my code for the .ui file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>TestSelectionDialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="TestSelectionDialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1366</width>
    <height>768</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="font">
   <font>
    <pointsize>15</pointsize>
   </font>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Settings</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset resource="resources.qrc">
    <normaloff>:/images/image.jpg</normaloff>:/images/image.jpg</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QGroupBox {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 3px;
 margin-top: 10 px
      
  }
 QGroupBox::title {
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
     left: 10px;
     padding: 0 3px 10 3px;
 }</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
     <property name="leftMargin">
      <number>5</number>
     </property>
     <property name="topMargin">
      <number>5</number>
     </property>
     <property name="rightMargin">
      <number>5</number>
     </property>
     <property name="bottomMargin">
      <number>5</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="logolabel">
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="pixmap">
        <pixmap resource="resources.qrc">:/images/logo2.png</pixmap>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="2">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="4">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0">
    <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeType">
      <enum>QSizePolicy::Expanding</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>40</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="3" column="1">
    <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
      <size>
       <width>20</width>
       <height>40</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </spacer>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="2">
    <widget class="QLabel" name="labelMemoryTest">
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Century Gothic</family>
       <pointsize>28</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color:white;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>SELECT OPTION</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="1" colspan="3">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <property name="spacing">
      <number>50</number>
     </property>
     <property name="leftMargin">
      <number>15</number>
     </property>
     <property name="topMargin">
      <number>15</number>
     </property>
     <property name="rightMargin">
      <number>15</number>
     </property>
     <property name="bottomMargin">
      <number>15</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>50</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadConfigButton">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>300</width>
           <height>150</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>15</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="toolTip">
          <string>Load Existing Configurations</string>
         </property>
         <property name="statusTip">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Button1</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadConfigButton_4">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>300</width>
           <height>150</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>15</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="toolTip">
          <string>Load Existing Configurations</string>
         </property>
         <property name="statusTip">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Button2</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>50</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>15</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadConfigButton_3">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>300</width>
           <height>150</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>15</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="toolTip">
          <string>Load Existing Configurations</string>
         </property>
         <property name="statusTip">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Button3</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadConfigButton_2">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>300</width>
           <height>150</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>15</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="toolTip">
          <string>Load Existing Configurations</string>
         </property>
         <property name="statusTip">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Button4</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the dialog's width is too small to have the image left to the centered title? Should they overlap? Should the layout move to the right? Should the image be scaled?

Comment: @MartinHennings I have set a minimum height and width to the dialog which will prevent from such a case happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGridLayout` doesn't seem sophisticated enough for that.

Try it with several nested widgets with simpler layouts:

test.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>448</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="1,0,1">
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_6">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>157</width>
             <height>27</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>100</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>100</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShape">
            <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShadow">
            <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_7">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
            <size>
             <width>157</width>
             <height>27</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </spacer>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>100</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>Title</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_5">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>147</width>
          <height>27</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Preferred</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>97</width>
          <height>108</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>200</width>
          <height>100</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>GroupBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeType">
         <enum>QSizePolicy::Preferred</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>97</width>
          <height>108</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```